# How do i create a loop that changes a boolean's value when the variable associated with that loop reaches a certain number

Tags: java

I'm writing a card game and I have a specific boolean which i have set to false, citizenLimiter. I want to set this boolean to true when the citizen card within my game is played a total of 4 times. This should allow it to stop you from playing the card and play a different card instead. My issue is that cardLimiter, the variable I am using to count the number of times the game is won, automatically sets citizenLimiter to true after the first use of the card. What do I need to do to fix this issue?

I've tried using a nested loop and have also tried setting the variable needed to change the value of the boolean to a different number.

```
public static void emperorsTurn() {
    if (cardLimiter <= 4){
        citizenLimiter = true;
    }

    Random cards = new Random();
    int computerinput = 0;
    int numberx = 5;

    for (int counter = 1; counter <= 3; counter++) {
        computerinput = 1 + cards.nextInt(2);
    }


    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please pick the card you are playing. \n if you are playing the Emperor press 1, if you are playing the citizen press 2 ");
    int userinput = sc.nextInt();

    if (userinput == 1 && computerinput == 1 && emperorLimiter == false) {
        System.out.println("you have played the emperor! \n the emperor is defeated by the slave");
        emperorLimiter =true;
        System.out.println("you can no longer use the emperor");
    } else if ((userinput == 1 && computerinput == 1 && emperorLimiter == true)) {
        System.out.println("you cannot play the emperor this turn \n you have played the citizen instead. The citizen is defeated by the slave");

        //make it so that the win/ lose is shown here


    } else if (userinput == 1 && computerinput == 2 && emperorLimiter == false) {
        System.out.println("you have played the emperor the emperor defeats the citizen");

        winOrLose();

        numberx--;
    } else if (userinput == 2 ) { //when the user input is 2
        if (computerinput == 1 && citizenLimiter == false) {
            System.out.println("you have played the citizen, this defeats the slave");

            cardLimiter++;
        } else if (computerinput == 2 && citizenLimiter == false) {
            System.out.println("you have played the citizen, this ties with the citizen");
            cardLimiter++;
        }
       if (computerinput==1 &&  citizenLimiter == true) {

               System.out.println("you are out of citizen cards, you play the emperor instead, this is defeated by the slave");
               //i need to make it so that once you are out of a certain type of card it plays the emperor instead


        }
        else if (computerinput == 2  && citizenLimiter == true ){

            System.out.println("you are out of citizen cards, you play the emperor instead,  this defeats the citizen");
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (cardLimiter <= 4)` read this code out loud to yourself. What is it doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it just be the other way?

```
if (cardLimiter > 4){
    citizenLimiter = true;
}
```

Comment: LOL thank you, this fixed it. i was so caught up in messing with other stuff I didn't understand that the problem was something so miniscule